# Inserting date in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, insert

datofreg is of type datetime

my command is

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into stud(datofreg) values('"+DateTime.Now+"'",conn);
```

when i execute it says Incorrect syntax near '1/6/2014 12:45:17 AM'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you are missing `)` at the end of your query but don't use this way..

```
"insert into stud(datofreg) values('" + DateTime.Now + "')"
                                                        ^^here
```

You should always use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

For example;

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into stud(datofreg) values(@date)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 for **parametrized queries**! That's the **only viable** way to go.

Comment: @marc_s Exactly! Besides prevent _SQL Injection_, also increases readability specially if sql query have a lot of parameters.